# How Cloud Run behaves with things that are running in my application during the deploy of a new service revision?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I'm migrating a PHP web application that currently runs on Compute Engine to Cloud Run. Currently, this platform schedules the execution of some PHP scripts in the form of cron jobs.

Let's say that I plan to use Cloud Scheduler to schedule requests to some of these PHP scripts after migrating to Cloud Run. My question is related to how Cloud Run will behave if any of these PHP scripts happen to be running during the end of a new deploy of a new service revision, would the deploy of a new revision kill the script execution (triggered by Cloud Scheduler request) in progress?

Also, I would like to know how Cloud Run behaves with (any) requests in progress during a new service revision deploy. Maybe both of my questions are related/connected.

(Maybe I am wrong when I think that the deploy of a new revision will immediately kill everything running and every request in progress to the service.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a new revision, the new request are routed to the new revision. The currently running request continue on the existing instances of the previous revisions. When there is no active request on an instance of the old revision, it will be deleted after a while (about 15 minutes today).

So, the 2 questions are related. But a remarks: If you run PHP script with Cloud Scheduler, the HTTP request that you perform must stay active up to the end of the script. If you send a response in your PHP script before the end on the processing, firstly the CPU will be throttle and you script will be very very very slow. And secondly, Cloud Run service will consider the instance as inactive (not serving active request) and can delete it as it wants.

Comment: Thanks, you clarified what I practically thought before but I still had a little doubt. It is good to have a background from someone certified, thank you very much.